# Getting around CORS issue with convert URL Image to binary

Tags: javascript, image, cors, blob

I pull some data from an API, and one of the properties is an image url. So i stick that url in the . However, I than need to take that image from the url, convert it binary so I can send it off to the DB to be stored, in binary form not just a url.

I've tried both approaches, one using the FileReader to convert to a blob, and the other where I write to a  and convert to a blob. However, with both approaches, the host of the Image from the URL gives me CORS rejection since the request is not coming from the same domain, which I understand. I don't have control over setting the headers on the other server, but I do need to convert the url image to binary. Is there anyway to do this without doing the conversion on my own server?

Comment: Really not a code snippet issue. Im not having issues with my code. Its more of an approach. But thanks

Comment: Don't think so. This is doing exactly what CORS is designed to do.

Comment: Try running your application in chrome browser with extension Allow-Control-Allow-Origin and then the browser will pass through CORS rejection but beware this might posses terrible security issues.

Comment: TL;DR - there is no way to bypass CORS - your only option is to use your own server to proxy the request to the remote server - you don't have to do any conversion, though, since the request is passing through, it probably makes more sense to convert on your server

Comment: @faizalvasaya *might posses some security issues*??? no *might* about it - it's a terrible extension to suggest :p

Comment: Ok you guys confirmed what I needed. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6):

You can use an open reverse proxy like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Instead of sending your request to `https://example.com/blob-source` you can instead send it to `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://example.com/blob-source` and the response will get sent back to the browser with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header and and any other necessary CORS response headers added.

Or you can get the source from https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/ and run your own proxy.